# Google Cloud Function response object: "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."

Tags: google-cloud-platform

help me...
I am creating a function (Http request) to zip images together with GCF. Images in Storage are registered from other functions.
One day, a few days after debugging, the title and response suddenly came back. I tried various things to see if it was an authentication problem, but it didn't work.

**stacktrace:**
functions: Beginning execution of "someFunction"
⚠ Google API requested!
--URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
--Be careful, this may be a production service.

**What I tried**
-IAM permissions for Cloud Storage
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions
-GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env
-Grant storage role "allusers"

Comment: Can you share your code that request the object in GCS?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere I was under no network connection for 3 days. Sorry.
`async function appendImageDatas(archive: archiver.Archiver, storageFolder: string,) {
  const bucket = storage.bucket();
  const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({
    prefix: `${storageFolder}`,
  });
  files.forEach(async (file) => {
    const fileName = file.name;
    console.log(`${file.name} : fetch test`);
    const appendfile = await bucket.file(`${fileName}`);
    const fileStream = await appendfile.createReadStream();
    //Zip add file
    archive.append(fileStream, {name: `${fileName}.jpg`});
}
`

Comment: Do you have app engine activated on your project?

Comment: No, it's inactive.  
Just in case, the error log of Functions of prod.  
log :
end with status code: 0

Function invocation was interrupted. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
Function invocation was interrupted. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging

Comment: Result of running with "firebase serve --only functions".  
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Can you try to activate App Engine on your project?